# Hibernate mapping classes from hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

For class mapping from hibernate.cfg.xml   I use these format below:

`<mapping class="packageName.className1"/>

<mapping class="packageName.className2"/>

<mapping class="packageName.className3"/>`

How can I map all classes in a package, by using one mapping row?
For Example: `<mapping class="packageName.*"/>` using bla-star doesn't work!

Comment: Try adding following property to enable auto scan `<property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm"/>`

Comment: Try: <mapping class="packageName.*"/>

Comment: <mapping class="packageName.*"/> –  doesn't work

Comment: `<property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm" />
 <mapping class="packageName.*"/>`
Error parsing XML: hibernate2.cfg.xml(22) Attribute "value" must be declared for element type "property".

Comment: Why don't you use `Java' based configuration to identify the classes you want to map?

Answer (score 0):

Error "Error parsing XML: hibernate2.cfg.xml(22) Attribute "value" must be declared for element type "property" -  is not related to package mapping.

`<mapping class="packageName.*"/>` should work.

Issue is with the `property` element.
`property` element doesnt have any attribute called `value`.

Try :

```
<property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection">class, hbm</property>
```

Instead of :

```
<property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm" />
```

Comment: My packagename = _05_one2one

Exception in thread "main" `org.hibernate.MappingException`: Unable to load class `[ _05_one2one.*]` declared in Hibernate configuration <mapping/> entry

Caused by: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: _05_one2one.*`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no direct way to scan packages from `hibernate.cfg.xml`. You can use other frameworks that wraps session factory creation with their own classes.

For example you can use `spring-orm` to scan packages while creating your session factory instance.

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="your-own-datasource"/>
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath*:hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="your.package.name"/>
</bean>
```

Or you can write your own SessionFactoryWrapper. While creating SessionFactory you can scan packages and than add them on runtime.

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.tools.FileObject;
import javax.tools.JavaFileObject;
import javax.tools.StandardJavaFileManager;
import javax.tools.StandardLocation;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

public class SessionFactoryWrapper {

    private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public SessionFactoryWrapper(final String...packagesToScan) {
        this.sessionFactory = this.createSessionFactory(packagesToScan);
    }

    private SessionFactory createSessionFactory(final String[] packagesToScan) {
        final Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure(); // Reads hibernate.cfg.xml from classpath

        for (String packageToScan : packagesToScan) {
            this.getEntityClasses(packageToScan).stream().forEach( configuration::addAnnotatedClass);
        }

        final ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
        return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    }

    private Collection<Class> getEntityClasses(final String pack) {
        final StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler().getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);
        try {
            return StreamSupport.stream(fileManager.list(StandardLocation.CLASS_PATH, pack, Collections.singleton(JavaFileObject.Kind.CLASS), false).spliterator(), false)
                    .map(FileObject::getName)
                    .map(name -> {
                        try {
                            final String[] split = name
                                    .replace(".class", "")
                                    .replace(")", "")
                                    .split(Pattern.quote(File.separator));

                            final String fullClassName = pack + "." + split[split.length - 1];
                            return Class.forName(fullClassName);
                        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }

                    })
                    .filter(aClass -> aClass.isAnnotationPresent(Entity.class))
                    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to use the solution with Spring Framework, but i've never used this framework before. Where am I going to write these xml codes(about spring framework). Is there any example about this solution which includes everything I must know.  As I said, I don't know anything about Spring Framework.
Thanks for help..

Comment: @user3174737 I have two different examples but both of them uses JPA API (still hibernate but a more generic api).  [First one](https://github.com/bhdrkn/Java-Examples/tree/master/spring-hibernate-5) uses Spring and Hibernate 5 with Spring-Boot. [Second One](https://github.com/bhdrkn/Java-Examples/tree/master/spring-jpa) Spring and Hibernate 4. I think second one is easier to understand.